# .htaccess несколько реддиректов

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть код реддиректа с https://domen.ru/test.jpg2 на https://domen.ru/test.jpg

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test.jpg$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.jpg2 [R=301,L]
```

Как мне сделать чтобы для каждой картинки с расширением .jpg2, .svg2, .png2 сделать реддирект на .jpg, .svg, .png

Comment: Прозрачный или 301 редирект нужен? И почему не перекидываешь на  нормальный jpg?

Answer (score 2):

Выбирай какой тебе больше нравиться вариант:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.((jpg)|(png)|(svg))2$ to/$1\.$2 [R=301,L] # 301
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.((jpg)|(png)|(svg))2$ to/$1\.$2 [QSA,NE,L] # Невидимый
```

> Док: https://habr.com/ru/post/154643/ и решение по доку:
> https://github.com/Roosso/MyScriptics/blob/master/.htaccess